# java webserver is not receiving requests from internet, Not Found error

Tags: java, apache, networking, webserver, fedora

I have restarted a project that i closed after it became too comfusing, the original project was a webserver run entirely from java code. I have started this back up in the hopes of making the code 100% my own using java. I have gotten to the testing stage of hosting website however whenever i try to connect from the outside world i am shutdown with an error page. I have note coded this error page and after extensive research it is viewable that the error page is originating from apache. The only problem with this is that there is no apache in the code or in the virtualbox server. I have also tested this on two different virtual servers: opensuse 13.1 and fedora 20.

The URL of the server is blends.hopto.org/beta. There should be a black background there with some arrows and a blue dot, but instead there is an error that states:
"Not Found
The requested URL /beta was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encounted while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

I do not get this error if i request the page from inside my local network. But i do from outside, it is not a port forwarding problem because my minecraft server works and the server is assigned to the public ip of my home router!

Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Extra info:
After positing this question i stumbled across some other problems and it seems that the error is originating from SELinux, however i have disabled SELinux and the error is still coming through!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay well i finally found out what the problem was after just looking over the assigned ips to devices and found it strange that our networked hard drive was assigned the very first ip always. So i logged into the hard drive and found out it had been capturing all the port 80 requests from the router in an attempt to do remote login!!! I am very excited that this problem is resolved! I will be hoping to release my WebServer API for everyone to use as it is incredibly small and gives the programmer full controll

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer.  I cannot comment on StackOverflow yet but would like to help.
You said that you get an Apache error page, which means that Apache must be running on your system.  You can check this by typing this in the terminal:

```
apachectl status
```

You don’t mention what port you want to serve on.  Apache usually uses port 80.  You could configure your homemade Java server to work on a different port, say 8080.  Also, if you are using Fedora 20, then you will have to configure FirewallD to allow this.

Comment: the webserver is running on any port i tell it to, but this error occurs on 80. Also from your command it says that apachectl is not installed